# Google Chrome freezes when my script is running

Tags: javascript, crash, freeze, phaser-framework

Context :
I'm making a version of the popular game, Snake. And I encounter some issues when I try to avoid the appearance of the food at the same place of the parts of my snake.

So I produced this code with the framework Phaser :

```
generateFood: function() {
        var randomX, randomY;
        var rightLocation = false;
        var foodOnSnake = false;

        while(rightLocation === false) {
            randomX = Math.floor(Math.random() * (this.game.width / squareSize)) * squareSize;
            randomY = Math.floor(Math.random() * (this.game.height / squareSize)) * squareSize;
            foodOnSnake = false;

            for (var i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) {
                if (snake[i].x === food.x && snake[i].y === food.y) {
                    foodOnSnake = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(foodOnSnake === false) {
                rightLocation = true;
            }
        }
        food = this.game.add.sprite(randomX, randomY, 'snake', 15);
    }
```

The aim, is to create some random coordinates on the game. And, while the food is generate on a part of the snake (the for loop), I will generate other coordinates. But for unknown reason, after my snake is eaten the first food, the game crashed and the tab of Google Chrome does not responding.
I think there is a mistake with a loop but I can't find it.

Comment: You have a number of undeclared objects/variables there.

Comment: add more of the definitions, especially the snake

Comment: and here you execute no matter what `food = this.game.add.sprite(randomX, randomY, 'snake', 15);` - as long as the while exits...

Comment: you have used snake[i].x === food.x && snake[i].y === food.y bt its ref missing.. what are they how you update them if you wont and they never equates you have a condition that result is never met...

Comment: I do not think it is "freezing" as much as burning a hole in your lap from your laptop there with that infinite loop.

Comment: like @Timo said it in the solution, I confused food.x and food.y (the expected food object) with randomX and randomY which are the desired coordinates. But, the other variables are well declared and defined earlier in my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You compare the coordinates of the snake's segments with `food.x` and `food.y`, which you never update inside the loop:

```
if (snake[i].x === food.x && snake[i].y === food.y) {
```

I believe you want to compare it to `randomX` and `randomY` instead:

```
if (snake[i].x === randomX && snake[i].y === randomY) {
```

---

Depending on the value of `food`'s coordinates, your function likely results in an infinite loop.

Comment: One of the problems it seems :)

Comment: An external point of view is often the solution, you solved my problem. Thank you a lot :)